# Style first child (if it's the first element)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to add padding to the first h2 child, only if it's the "first element" inside the parent.

```
<div id="test">
    <h2>Try 1</h2>
    Test Test Test
    <h2>Try 2</h2>
</div>
```

here only h2 with text "Try 1" must get my custom padding.

```
<div id="test">
    Test Test Test
    <h2>Try 1</h2>
    <h2>Try 2</h2>
</div>
```

Here no (there is text before).

Tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SPnwX/1/) :

```
h2
{
    padding-top:0;
}

#test h2:first-child
{
    padding-top:40px;
}​
```

but it is no enough! Can I do this with CSS2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if it's the very first child node? No, unfortunately, not with CSS selectors, since non-element nodes are invisible to CSS selectors (with the exception of attribute selectors and `:empty`).

Comment: With jquery? Can I test it?

Comment: if h2 is the first "element" inside a parent (before or after text also, not a specific element...)

Comment: You should be able to with plain JavaScript: `document.getElementById('test').firstChild.nodeName == 'H2'`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CUwRc/ check the example

example css:

```
 div h2:nth-of-type(1) {
   background:red;
  }​
```

IE9+ support only I'm afraid, rest of the browsers ok!

Comment: Try it with the code given in the question and you'll see that it doesn't work.

Comment: No, it's not supposed to turn red when the text node is there.

Comment: I see your point. So I guess is not posible by pure css methods